# Importing Newtype(s) from another module

Tags: purescript, newtype

I'm learning PureScript lately and did a small application that draws a cube on the screen. All is well and I had a few `newtype`s defined in the top of the `Main` module as follows:

```
newtype Vec2 = Vec2
    {
        x :: Number
    ,   y :: Number
    }

newtype Vec3 = Vec3
    {
        x :: Number
    ,   y :: Number
    ,   z :: Number
    }
```

I also got some functions that does transformations such as `perspectiveDivide` etc., that I want to move to another module `Transforms` just to organize better. So I moved these types to the Transforms module, and exported them.

```
module Transforms (Vec2, Vec3, perspectiveDivide) where
```

and the above types follows this.

Now I tried to import these in the main module with the selective import feature, but it didn't work.

```
import Transforms (Vec2, Vec3, perspectiveDivide)
```

but it still gave me an error when trying to use a function `projectToScreen` which was still in the main module. The error is like this:

> in module Main   at src/Main.purs line 30, column 10 - line 30, column
>   18
>
> ```
> Unknown data constructor Vec3
> ```
>
> See
>   https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/UnknownName.md
>   for more information,   or to contribute content related to this
>   error.

I'm both new to functional programming and also PureScript. What does this error mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`module Transforms (Vec2, Vec3, perspectiveDivide) where` only exports the type constructors.

You want to use `Vec2(..)` to export the data constructors as well. The same syntax works for the imports.